# Old sci-fi book about cat people at war with humans, guy in biodome thing

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember the title of this book. A scientist guy is on a space ship when it is attacked by these cat people which humans are at war with I think? I think he escapes somehow and lands/ends up in a biodome with extinct species like mammoths and other things. Eventually he finds a room with sleeping specimens of random alien species and one of them is the cat species which he wakes up one. The rest is hazy but I remember he had this cool flying chair/scooter thing. Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found the book it is called cat house and it's a part of the man kzin series.